# Are questions regarding glitches or exploits in online games allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we stand on cheats, in particularly for multiplayer games?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/how-do-we-stand-on-cheats-in-particularly-for-multiplayer-games)

Suppose I had a question about an exploit in Diablo 3 that allows a character to go from level 1 to 60 in 10 hours, is that considered on topic or too localized (it'll become obsolete once it gets patched at some point)?

Comment: Queue argument about what's considered to be an exploit!

Answer (score 0):

If the glitch is likely to be patched, I would say the question should be closed as "Too Localized" since

> This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only
>   relevant to a small geographic area, **a specific moment in time**, or an
>   extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to
>   the worldwide audience of the internet.

However if the glitch is for an old game that is no longer supported and will not ever change, I would say it's fair game :)

Comment: Specifically regarding Diablo 3 and Blizzard games, exploiting a glitch will get your account banned. http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/exploitation-policy . So sharing it here, at all, doesn't sound like a great idea.

Comment: @Resorath Didn't realize that, thanks :) I removed that part of my answer since its unrelated to the question anyways

Comment: @Resorath So I guess all the FA wizards and SS DH who got to flood AH with level 60 items are all gone now? The guys farming with Tyrael too ofc. ;)