# Where do we stand on cheating in single player games?

Tags: discussion, cheats

From what I can see in meta, it appears that the community generally agrees that, provided the cheating isn't about multiplayer games, that it is perfectly on topic.

See: [How do we stand on cheats, in particularly for multiplayer games?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/how-do-we-stand-on-cheats-in-particularly-for-multiplayer-games)

But despite this I've just had a question placed ON HOLD because I asked about cheats in a single player game. Has the community changed their mind on the issue of discussing cheats here?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do we stand on cheats, in particularly for multiplayer games?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/489/how-do-we-stand-on-cheats-in-particularly-for-multiplayer-games)

Comment: Also of http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8181/cheats-as-an-answer I suppose

Comment: Relevant question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197628/is-there-any-way-to-cheat-hack-tiny-death-star-on-ios

Comment: For the record, I voted to close as, "Too Broad".  Just asking if there a possibility of cheating isn't really useful, and carries the implication of listing said cheats or hacks.

Answer (score 8):

For reference, here is the question in...question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197628/is-there-any-way-to-cheat-hack-tiny-death-star-on-ios

It shouldn't have been closed as off topic for being about cheats, since those are fine, in single player games. Play however makes you happy as long as you're not negatively impacting others.

However, it should have been closed as off topic for being a recommendation question, since you're just asking for open ended recommendations that may or may not exist. I'm not going to bother opening it and re-closing it for the correct reason; it's already in the right place even if it didn't get there for 100% the right reasons.

Comment: The problem is that, by their nature, cheats are often open ended and hard to predict. In the case of TINY DEATH STAR, I would like infinite Bux, but it seems silly to open up an entirely new question to ask if there's a cheat for infinite Gold, or unlockable levels, don't you think?

Comment: @django There are good old traditional cheat sites for that, even though they consider achievements to be cheats in order to pad their contents. I'd rather do things the SE way if possible.

Comment: Well I've narrowed the question down, even though I disagree. I assume it will be taken off hold now?

Comment: This particular question isn't a great example of a "single-player game cheat question," because as I mentioned in my comment there, the question is *really* asking about how to circumvent the game's monetization and get unlimited F2P currency without having to pay for it.

Comment: It isn't a question about single player cheats, it is a question about hacking iOS app DRM. Close it.

Comment: So, people, can we go back to the core of the question and talk about cheating in offline, singleplayer games?

Comment: Your part about negatively impacting others on a single player game is very wrong.  How does an isolated game affect others when there is no interaction?  I should suggest you edit this to avoid some strong opinionated confusion. On another level how does Game shark codes fall under this rule as well?  How does certain hidden button pressing(some back in the day were considered cheats because they were not well known.) or secret levels considered OT? right now your answer states all of what I said is considered OT.

Comment: @Virus I think you misunderstood the answer. I said those questions are fine.