# Is asking how to hack Pokémon necessarily a multiplayer cheat?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, scope, pokemon, cheats

We have a [broad](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11190/161932) question on cheating in primarily single-player games that have a multi-player aspect. I want to ask about applying this principle specifically to Pokémon main-series games. These games are primarily single-player but also have options to use the Pokémon you have gathered in the single-player campaign to trade and/or battle with the wider world.

Specifically, the recent question [Can I date spoof to access special Wild Area raids after the event period?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/391517/161932) seems to fit this model. It's asking about setting a false date in the console in order to trigger the appearance of special event-bound Pokémon whose events have already ended.

On a personal note, I really won't get my panties in a bunch if someone wants to do this in their campaign, or even hack themselves a full party of level 100 100% IV legendary birds with adamant natures for that matter, but I do mind if these Pokémon may end up coming to me in a mystery trade or facing me in an online battle. Even if someone swears up and down that they will keep their hacked Pokémon offline, a simple change of heart or even a mistake can result in them getting online and affecting other players.

So, do questions about how to cheat in single-player Pokémon campaigns fall under our [policy against asking for multiplayer cheats](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/489/161932)?

Comment: Related: [Asking questions about cheating in games that have a multiplayer setting?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14674/4797)

Answer (score 4):

**No**, but only if the title requires players to be in the same physical vicinity as one another (e.g. generation IV and newer is out of the question entirely).

<sub>*The **no** is answering the question's title here.*</sub>

---

There is a *very* concise list of Pokémon titles that fall under my stance on the matter, and they were all released *prior* to generation four. These titles have specific [hardware requirements](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Trade#Hardware_requirements) as they were born in the era of the [Game Link cable](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Game_Link_Cable) and the [GBA Wireless Adapter](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Game_Boy_Advance_Wireless_Adapter):

> Prior to FireRed and LeafGreen, trading required a Game Link Cable. FireRed, LeafGreen, and Emerald can trade using a GBA Wireless Adapter or a Game Link Cable. From Generation IV onwards, trading uses wireless communication and does not require additional hardware.

These items ***require*** players to be in the same physical space as one another in order for multiplayer connections to work, and as such I believe it is perfectly okay to request assistance with mods and hacks. This is due to the fact that the players involved can physically inspect (and sometimes do) each other's game before any trades or battles are initiated and confirmed.