# Would a question asking about the extents of rules be allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

For example, Runescape does not allow bots. I want to ask a question to figure out the extent of this, as I have an idea for a "bot" that falls within the rules on the rules page. Would a question asking for clarification about if something would be rule breaking be allowed?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the question.

Asking for general clarifications on server/online rules or clauses from a game's Terms of Service (TOS) etc is generally fine. We've had those sorts of questions before and they are generally well received.

Asking if a particular technique would get you into trouble/banned/suspended etc is only really answerable by the Game Developer/Support team - it's their game and their TOS to enforce as they see fit, even if gamers might think the technique is 'ok' from a gameplay perspective.

Asking if a technique is considered cheating/botting by the community surrounding the game? Ok, we might be able to answer that one, but bear in mind our [rules around](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/492/28182) cheating in [multiplayer games](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10318/28182).

Comment: Alright, I am mainly going for clarification on the TOS, as from what I read it SHOULD be allowed.

Comment: @ShadowZ. yeah it should be fine then :)