# Can I ask for cheat codes and mods on this site?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, cheats

Can I ask for cheat codes of a game on this forum? And can I ask for mods for an Android game here?

Comment: Related: [How do we stand on cheats, in particularly for multiplayer games?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/489/28182)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If a developer designed a cheat to exist, then yes, that is absolutely on topic. This includes modding capabilities - if the game supports mods, then most questions in this realm are okay here.

If a developer did not design a cheat to exist, or if a game is not supposed to support mods but they exist anyway, then it might step into the realm of illegal content. That depends on the context of the question itself, and is determined by the community whether it is on topic.

Answer (score 19):

In general, asking about built-in cheat codes is fine for single-player games. But not cheats for [multiplayer games](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/how-do-we-stand-on-cheats-in-particularly-for-multiplayer-games) (not that many multiplayer games have built-in cheats).

If the (single-player) game requires mods to cheat, it is probably a better idea to ask something like "how to do I get unlimited money in [game]?" and allow the answers to suggest mods, rather than asking "What mod gives me unlimited money in [game]?"

---

I would avoid asking about modded android games. For a few reasons;

- The question might get closed for asking for "[Recommendations for **software**, hardware, games, or genres.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)"
- Modded .apk files can contain additional malicious code (viruses, spyware, etc)
- Like with cheats, we would not support questions that ask for a modded client for a multiplayer game.