# Asking questions about cheating in games that have a multiplayer setting?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, cheats

So, a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/358641/are-there-any-working-item-duplication-glitches-on-a-minecraft-1-14-4-server-run) has been posted recently about exploiting glitches in Minecraft; which is effectively cheating.

The base rule for Arqade is that we [do not support this in Multiplayer games](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/how-do-we-stand-on-cheats-in-particularly-for-multiplayer-games).

> I don't care about cheating in single-player games / game modes at all, but cheats in multiplayer games (including using external programs like wallhacks and such) are absolutely deplorable, and **I would hate to see this site turn into a place where you can get answers to questions regarding cheats in multiplayer games.**

However, Minecraft is a bit of a grey area. There are many different ways to play this in Multiplayer, sometimes with the simple push of a button.

This particular question *does* state that it is in the situation of a multiplayer game, and the reasons for closing use this as a valid reason. The OP has clearly stated they want to cheat in a multiplayer setting, which we do not support.

However, by simply removing a few words, does this make it ok?

There have been other questions about cheating in games that have been deemed fine - [as they are not able to be played in multiplayer settings](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/where-do-we-stand-on-cheating-in-single-player-games) - games that do not have multiplayer capacity, or games that no longer have servers to support this.

So the question is: Regardless of whether or not the OP has stated their situation, should cheating be automatically off-topic for games that *can* be played in a multiplayer setting?

Comment: Related (if not a duplicate): https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14658/can-i-ask-for-cheat-codes-and-mods-on-this-site

Comment: I don't think that there should be a blanket ban on cheating for all multiplayer games. For example, in Borderlands 2: [How do I set my level, unlocked weapon equip slots and playthrough mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/111815/4797) - This is technically cheating on a multiplayer co-op game, but the kind that is favorable to players involved (because in this game, it is preferable to play with players that are around the same level as you). I think each question should be judged on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Exactly. You can do these things in a single player setting, but you can also do this in a multiplayer setting, simply by switching from one to the other

Comment: I think the/an important factor is if the game is competitive or not. Ie. getting wallhacks to work in counter-strike single player mode shouldn't be allowed while getting wallhacks to work in borderlands should be since it's only friends you can play with anyway.

Comment: Borderlands is multiplayer, but not in the same way counter-strike is. Aequitas is correct, Borderlands is a story driven game and your level/quest status just affects your playthrough with your friends. There is no competitive advantage against others. In Minecraft, items ARE the advantage and economy - no one cares if you have a thousand guns in Borderlands, but having a thousand diamonds in Minecraft without earning them breaks the multiplayer setting in which the game is played.

Comment: @Aequitas and `@FoxMcCloud Just wanted to correct: "*borderlands should be since it's only friends you can play with anyway*" and "*Borderlands is a story driven game... [that] just affects your playthrough with your friends*". Borderlands can also be set to play in a public lobby (i.e. non-friends can also join lobbies).

Answer (score 2):

You bring up an interesting point. I think its important to read into the intent of the question. The intent of this question is to find out how to cheat in a multiplayer setting, which would be off-topic. Just because you COULD do this on your own server, doesn't mean 99.9999% of the people reading this question will. We don't want to spread questions like this around and allow them.

Comment: "*The intent of this question is to find out how to cheat in a multiplayer setting, which would be off-topic.*" I think you should clarify this to be more specific (see Borderlands 2 example I mentioned in the question's comments, as an example of an on-topic "cheating in a multiplayer setting" question). Why is this disadvantageous to players involved? The way in which this answer is currently worded makes it seem like it's in favor of a blanket-ban on asking about *all* kinds of cheating in *any* multiplayer setting.

Comment: @galacticninja The question that is posted is the reason for my answer. You're talking about the game that was brought up in the comments, which has nothing to do with my answer. My comment below the question that talks about how borderlands is different than minecraft will tell you that I'm NOT in favor of blanket bans.

Comment: The question is asking about the general case, so I assumed that this answer is also about the general case, and not a specific question. Since you're not in favor of blanket bans, maybe you should clarify why for this specific question. Quoting the question: "*So the question is: Regardless of whether or not the OP has stated their situation, should cheating be automatically off-topic for games that can be played in a multiplayer setting?*"