# Should this (kind of adult-themed) nethack question have been deleted?

Tags: discussion, adult

Ok, so back in August I saw an entry in a public nethack highscores file that listed "choked on an attempt at self-fellatio" as the reason of death. I've asked a question about this here, which was then promptly deleted for being too adult-themed.

I've also received a nice email by Juan Manuel about this in which he linked to the meta discussion about [adult-themed gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/adult-themed-gaming). Since nethack isn't an adult-themed game by any stretch, I'm not sure whether that discussion applies. I do see his point though - the question was kind of adult-themedish.

Juan also suggested I ask a question on meta if I disagree with his decision. But since I didn't feel too strongly about it at the time, I just left it alone.

However I've since found the answer to my question - it isn't anything dirty and I think it's actually quite clever. I figure it's a shame that I can't post this answer for posterity.

So now I'm taking Juan up on his offer after all and open this up for discussion: Should the question have been deleted?

Comment: I *would* just [provide the link for 10k users](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5257/title-got-sanitized), but that's just tzenes for now. Instead, I will note that the content of the question is just noting the information from the first sentence here, and asking how it was done. *[ninja star]: cleansed link slug*

Comment: @Grace You left out that that was the title of the question as well, based on the link there.

Comment: @C. Ross I kinda guessed it was implicit, but yes, the title is "How can I" said act.

Comment: I *do* write the most beautiful e-mails

Comment: @Grace Note -- Hey now, I'm almost up there too! :(

Comment: That's _quite_ the link

Answer (score 10):

- **No policy has been violated.** Let's *quote* them policies:

  > **Sexually Explicit Material.** Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended. <sub>[source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy)</sub>
  >   Including adult links, or even mentioning adult sites by name, is explicitly not allowed. <sub>[source](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/are-questions-about-adult-web-apps-on-or-off-topic)</sub>

  - The term used there is scientific, *not* sexually explicit or pornographic. Besides, if the term is the problem, *it should simply have been edited out*.
  - The question does not link to adult sites.
  - The game is not adult in nature.
- **Next user with this question will ask the question again.** By deleting the question, *nothing has really been solved.*
- Corporate filters will block the site anyway (reason: *gaming*).
- Bold titles help the site gain popularity -- see [How can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat)

The question is fine in my eyes, sorry.

Comment: So for our non-English speaking residence the term "sexually explicit" means `words or images which expresses, demonstrates, describes or shows, an act of sex`.  Discussing someone's death by using the terms `self fDIRTYWORDHERE` falls into that definition.  Now I don't mean to suggest any recourse for this question, merely point out that it was Sexually Explicit in nature.

Comment: i was under the impression fellatio was the technical term for it, not a dirty word. It's about as medical sounding as you can get. Googling it leads directly to wikipedia where the kids can learn that it's just a new word for something they already known to them as ***********.

Answer (score 1):

As Grace Note states [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/933/how-to-handle-questions-which-may-require-a-seedy-answer/935#935), questions should be closed based on their own merits, not based on their (possible) answers.

Based on that, I would say a question that seems to clearly reference adult content should be closed, even if it turns out the answer is not "adult".

Comment: That is a good point, but even without knowing the answer I found it incredibly hard to believe that nethack (which really is a pretty family friendly game) would contain anything sexually explicit.

Comment: @sepp2k The nurse dance is kind of ... weird.

Comment: @CRoss: The nurse needs you to strip down so she can properly examine you. It's only dirty if your mind is :p

Comment: @sepp And what about certain demons?

Comment: @grace: Ok, fine, I give up, you guys win. Nethack is pornographic, I admit it. But to be fair: the message only says "You and the succubus lie in each other's arms. You feel exhausted.".

Comment: @Sepp on an unrelated note I think I found [your answer](http://www.gameskb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/games-nethack/4344/question-about-alt-org)

Comment: @sepp True. That is more of a "sexually implicit" description.

Answer (score -6):

Yes, it should have been deleted.

For multiple reasons including.

- That sort of thing might get the site blocked by filters (corporate and otherwise).
- There are kids about.
- It's the policy.