# Are questions about mods on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Are questions about mods to game on topic?

For example "How can I play as infernal in [Fall From Heaven II](http://kael.civfanatics.net/About.shtml)" for Civ IV.

---

Related: [What's the stance on mods to PC games?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361/whats-the-stance-on-mods-to-pc-games)

Comment: I'd say mod-playing yes, but mod-making should be handled at gamedev, see [Do mod- and map-making questions belong here?](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/58/252)

Comment: I just can't stand that Minecraft Mod support is off topic!

Comment: @JimJones See [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10390/4797) and [What exactly is technical support?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11015/4797) for the policy RE: Minecraft mods tech support. Basically, only tech support for modded Minecraft *crash* issues are off-topic.

Answer (score 18):

I don't see why not? A Mod like "Fall From Heaven" is essentially another game that happens to be built on an existing one. And we don't exclude games based on platform or genre in general, I see nothing about this specific case that would be problematic.

As for other mods, we've had plenty of questions like [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6179/how-to-improve-animations-and-textures-in-fallout-3-goty) about mods to improve the baseline experience of a game - and I certainly don't see why they *wouldn't* be germane to our mission.

Comment: Fully agreed. We even have a separate tag for [Defense of the Ancients](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defense-of-the-ancients), which isn't a game at all but simply a Warcraft 3 map. So a mod to a game that is an actively played game is, for all intents and purposes that we need to care about, on-topic.

Answer (score 15):

Questions about mods should definitely be on-topic, whether they are prominent or not.

Answer (score 10):

Questions for all mods are on topic. However, if the mod or the game is too obscure, we may not able to answer you. Give a download link if possible to help us help you.

Answer (score -7):

Questions about mods are off topic. However, the following should be not posting:

1. Requesting for a mod to use.
2. If it's Minecraft mods, don't ask question about tech support for modded Minecraft. only ask question for vanilla.
3. Mod making. Please post that at gamedev stack exchange.
4. Other rules the post violates.

So far, yes questions about mods can be asked.

Comment: Can you clarify this post? At the first part of your post you say, "*Questions about mods are off topic*", then at the last part, "*yes questions about mods can be asked.*" Those statements contradict each other.