# Are a game's mod questions a good fit for this community?

Tags: discussion, asking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are questions about prominent mods on topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/are-questions-about-prominent-mods-on-topic)

I have been having problems with mods crashing my game. I asked a question about it [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52549/mallus-maccius-no-longer-a-fence).

I was able to solve most problems with my situation.

In this regard I do not know if I should answer my own question or not. The steps that I took to resolve the problem, can that serve as an answer?

It did not receive as much attention from the gaming public. Was it because it was about mods? But it got one vote.

In general is it OK to ask about particular mods, problem with mods as they pertain to a particular game?

I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Questions about mods are okay, as you can see in the duplicate question. Regarding your 3rd paragraph - you may certainly answer your own question if you came up with a solution! Please do! This can help any future visitor encountering the same problem. The [FAQ] also explicitly permits answering your own question.

Comment: If you are asking about a mod, though, please make it clear in the question itself, and possibly also add a tag for the mod, if it's significant enough.

Comment: It will hope those that have the exact same mods installed. A smaller selection of players, of course, but still a valid question.