# Are Questions about mods compatibility on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

As per [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/are-questions-about-mods-on-topic), it is clear that Questions about Mods themselves or their gameplay are on-topic.

What I am not clear about is, are questions about mutual compatibility of two mods on-topic? For example:

"Are mod A and B for Game X compatible with each other? How can I run them together?"

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't see a problem with this type of question, as long as it's restricted to "Does Mod A work with Mod B?" and not "What mods does Mod A work with?"  You could even extend the list beyond just 2 mods, although what the upper limit would be is a little harder to pin down.

Comment: @MBraedley Of course that would be a List-question and should be closed as too-broad as there might be countless mods which work well together.

Comment: As long as you're not asking how to get two mods working together for Minecraft; that'd fall into Minecraft mod tech support, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no problem with this type of question. It's a bit of a slippery slope though; it could easily lead into a mod troubleshooting question, which tends to be off topic here. But, if the question is simply looking for someone's expertise in some mods that may or may not be compatible, that's certainly within Arqade's scope.